# Flycut icon disappears when I open Word

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar

My Flycut clipboard icon in the top ribbon disappears when I open Word - the program where I most need it! I think it's just lack of space. The large icon in the bottom dock doesn't hold my cuttings.

How can I access the missing icon? Can I change the position of other items in the top ribbon (date, volume, etc.) so the ones I need in Word are available? Or can I remove my name, which I don't need?

MacBook Air, OS X 10.11.5

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need your name shown in the menu bar, go to System Preferences → Users & Groups → Login Options and either uncheck ‘Show fast user switching menu as’ or change it to Icon to make more room.

If you update to macOS Sierra 10.12, you can rearrange all menu bar items by ⌘-dragging them.

Comment: That worked and I can now use my Flycut clipboard again.  Much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: @PHarrison Welcome to Ask Different! If an answer solved your question, you can mark it accepted using the check mark on the left under the voting buttons, cheers.